# Way to call a static method of a class template without specifying an instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to define a static method in a class template which can be then be called without specifying the instantiation?

I think this could be useful in cases where you have some auxiliary static function, which logically belongs in a class (which happens to be a template one), but doesn't depend on the template parameter.

I don't mind either:

1. Having the same static method (including address and all) for all
   instantiations, or
2. Having a separate static method for each instantiation, but be able to call the static method without
   specifying an instantiation where I call the method (some default
   would be called).

e.g.

```
template<typename T> class C {
public:
    static int func() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    // This works.
    return C<int>::func();   

    // These don't work.
    // return C<>::func();   
    // return C::func();   
}
```

Comment: If there is no dependency on the template instantiation, why not make it an ordinary, free static (or non-static) function?

Comment: "I think this could be useful in cases where you have some auxiliary static function, which logically belongs in a class"

Comment: You may add some incorrect default template parameter like `template<typename T = void>` so using such object won't work, but your method will be callable without specifying template arguments. `C<>::func()`

Comment: @Danra Why would it "logically belong in a class"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to have the static function belong in a base class, and then the template derives from the base:

```
struct CBase {
    static int func() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T> class C : public CBase {
public:
};

int main()
{
    // This works.
    return C<int>::func();

    // This will work too:
    return CBase::func();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use inheritance which will also remove the duplication of any non static functions ( that also don't care about the template type ) in your binary, i.e:

```
class A {
public:
    static int func() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T> 
class B : A {

};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get `C` or `C<>` to work you can either rely on a base non-template class that contains the given function or use template specializations as it follows:

```
template<typename...>
struct C;

template<>
struct C<> {
    static int func() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
struct C<T>: C<> {
    // all the other things around...
};

int main() {
    C<int>::func();   
    C<>::func();   
}
```

For you don't provide a definition for the primary template, accepted specializations are:

- `C<>` that contains only the given function
- `C<T>` that accepts only a parameter as it was in the original example

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LABLGvosAWWv1LNC).

---

If you can't use variadic templates, you can still do something similar with a custom type.
As an example:

```
struct func_only {};

template<typename T = func_only>
struct C;

template<>
struct C<func_only> {
    static int func() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
struct C: C<func_only> {
    // all the other things around...
};

int main() {
    C<int>::func();   
    C<>::func();   
}
```

---

That being said, make it a free function looks to me as the best solution anyway.

Comment: That's clever!  It has the advantage that `C<>` is obviously (to a reader) closely related to `C<int>`.  It has the disadvantage that I couldn't write it.

Comment: @MartinBonner Why not? The question hasn't any tag, I've assumed C++11 or later revision. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Sorry, by "I couldn't write it", I meant "I don't have the technical skill to come up with that"!  The compiler at work would have no trouble with it.

Answer (score -1):

How would that work? You typically depend on the type in your static functions too.

```
template<typename T> class C {
public:
    static int func() { return sizeof(T); }
};
```

If they do not depend on it, you should probably make them free functions, or static members of a base class of this class.

Comment: "I think this could be useful in cases where you have some auxiliary static function, which logically belongs in a class (which happens to be a template one), *but doesn't depend on the template parameter.*"

Comment: Then it's still part of the template class. You could also just accept this part and leave the linker to merge them under Identical Code Folding...